# Using environment variables in dotnet restore in Dockerfile

Tags: .net, dockerfile

I'm running into an issue where it seems that I'm unable to translate environment variables in my docker file. At least, not for the `dotnet restore` command.

In my Dockerfile I have the following:

```
ARG PACKAGE_FEED_URL
ENV PACKAGE_FEED_URL ${PACKAGE_FEED_URL}
RUN echo Feed selected: $PACKAGE_FEED_URL
...
RUN dotnet restore -s "$PACKAGE_FEED_URL" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" "Invoker/Invoker.Main.csproj"
```

As you can see, I'm outputting the value of the $PACKAGE_FEED_URL and this works:

```
Step 8/42 : RUN echo Feed selected: $PACKAGE_FEED_URL
 ---> Running in b6b52910f2c2
Feed selected: https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/My_Artifacts/nuget/v3/index.json
```

But `dotnet restore` tries to use the environment variable literally as I observed from the logs:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -s "$PACKAGE_FEED_URL" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" "Invoker/Invoker.Main.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I already tried different scenario's like `${PACKAGE_FEED_URL}`, `"${PACKAGE_FEED_URL}"`, `$PACKAGE_FEED_URL` and `"$PACKAGE_FEED_URL"`

How is it possible that the environment variable is not resolved *only* for the dotnet restore command?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. You should share your whole dockerfile better yet to prepare a test scenario that fails reproducably so we can debug it.

```
FROM bitnami/dotnet-sdk:6-debian-10
ARG PACKAGE_FEED_URL
ARG CSPROJ

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY Api/*.csproj ./Api/
RUN dotnet restore "$CSPROJ" -s "$PACKAGE_FEED_URL"
```

`docker build --no-cache --build-arg CSPROJ="./Api/Api.csproj" --build-arg PACKAGE_FEED_URL="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" -f "Dockerfile" -t testimage .`

```
[+] Building 15.7s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/dotnet-sdk:6-debian-10                                                                 0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/bitnami/dotnet-sdk:6-debian-10                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 59B                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [3/4] COPY Api/*.csproj ./Api/                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [4/4] RUN dotnet restore "./Api/Api.csproj" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"                                                 12.5s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                    3.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                   3.0s
 => => writing image sha256:3437bfd2cdb7d70e8e90730b66a1acd4bd7a0ad2939155071c2c8f87ae749c9a                                              0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/testimage
```

Also great article about ENV and ARG parameters: https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/